# Issue setting up HTTPS over a cname

Tags: heroku, web, https, cname

So I developed my RoR website on heroku. I used https on heroku and I recently bought a domain for my website. So I setup www.mydomain.com to cname to myapp.herokuapp.com.

But the problem is that when you browse over to www.mydomain.com you get a browser warning 
saying

```
You attempted to reach www.mydomain.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. 
An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.mydomain.com.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.
```

I was wondering how I can fix this error from showing up when you browse to https://www.mydomain.com

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SSL on your own domain you will need to purchase a SSL domain for your domain and then use the Heroku SSL endpoint addon ($20 a month). https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint.